# Java TCP server side - Send message to selected client from JList area

Tags: java, arrays, network-programming, jlist

[image]

As you can see from the picture The clients can talk to each other, and the admin too.

But what I want is to send a message to whoever is selected in the JList.

```
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
          public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {

              //if evt == selected source
                for(int i = 1; i <= GUI.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){
                    //loop through the array and see if the Index matches with the Index in the list

                    //send message to the index
                }


          }
        });
```

That's the PSEUDO code I have, but I don't know how to implement it. Can someone please give me a solution.

This is how I add users to the List btw

```
protected void AddUserToList(Socket socket) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("Client accepted from: " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
     Scanner input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
     String name = input.nextLine();
     UsersOnline.add(name);
     System.out.println(name);
     dlm.addElement(name);
     list.setModel(dlm);
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
     out.println("Thanks for joining my server " + name);
     out.flush();
}
```

And these four are global

```
public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();
public static ArrayList<String> UsersOnline = new ArrayList<String>();
JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();
```